# Rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, count, row

I have a csv file consisting of various dates. How do I count the number of events per day for every hour? The output should have rows (representing days) and columns (representing hours).

Comment: You need to give us [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't even know what your data look like.

Comment: I'm not sure what code to use for this as I'm very new to python. However, I have included a picture on what the first few data sets look like.

Comment: You should paste at least part of your csv file.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be create the binned event counts, then extend the resulting `DataFrame` to cover the entire month, and `pivot_table` to produce the desired row/column format. Assuming your `DataFrame` is called `df`, this would look like the following:

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df.REGIS_DATE + ' ' + df.REGIS_TIME, dayfirst=True)
index = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=24*31, freq='H')
events = df.set_index('datetime').resample('H').count().REGIS_DATE.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
pd.DataFrame(events).pivot_table(index=events.index.date, columns=events.index.hour)
```

Example input `df`:

```
   REGIS_DATE REGIS_TIME
0  20/01/2011   23:07:42
1  26/01/2011   12:14:35
2  11/01/2011   14:34:29
3  11/01/2011   17:53:17
4  29/01/2011   11:02:32
```

Corresponding output:

```
           REGIS_DATE
               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
2011-01-01      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-02      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-03      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-04      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-05      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-06      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-07      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-08      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-09      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-10      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-11      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-12      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-13      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-14      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-15      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-16      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-17      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-18      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-19      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-20      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
2011-01-21      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-22      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-23      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-24      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-25      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-26      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-27      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-28      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-29      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-30      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
2011-01-31      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Comment: Is there a way to use numpy to get similar results?

Comment: You could always convert the `datetime64[ns]` to `np.int64` and perform the binning on those, and then just reshape to get your desired output, but doing so would be much more error-prone, less elegant altogether, and it seems that the labeling is the main part of your requirements, so I'm not sure what you would be aiming to gain from doing so.